# if statement issue on .ts file in React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I write a simple "if" statement in a ".ts" file of React app, but the "if" doesn't work, the code is as follow:

```
const a = `555`;

if (0<1) 
{
    const a = `333`;
}
```

In the end, however, the value of "a" is `555` !!!
Would you please guide me?

Comment: Why decrease "2" in my reputation??
I check the similarity of my question and no one asked this question!
I cannot accept this behaviour that people are criticized for asking questions!

Comment: `const` creates a _new_ variable that only exists inside `{` and `}`